# How do I use #from to convert nom parsing errors into my thiserror error variant?

Tags: rust, nom, thiserror

Consider this snippet:

```rust
use thiserror::error;

pub fn parse_something(input: &str) -> Result<i32, MyError> {
    let (_, number) = nom::number::complete::i32(input)?;
    Ok(number)
}

// define error
#[derive(Error, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("Parsing error in the input")]
    ParseError(#[from] nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&'static str>>),
}
```

It won't compile because apparently the

> borrowed data escapes outside the function

I'm a bit stumped. I just want to catch all the parsing errors in a nice way and return that variant.

I could always use `map_err` in `parse_something`, but I thought the `#[from]` macro exists precisely so I don't *have* to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working in your snippet is because the lifetime of `input` is elided, so the Rust compiler assigns a distinct lifetime (e.g. `'a`) to `input`. Your function (after expanding the lifetime) looks like this to the compiler:

```rust
pub fn parse_something<'a>(input: &'a str) -> Result<i32, MyError>
```

The lifetime `'a`, unless manually specified by you, is assumed to be shorter than `'static`. The error is expecting the lifetime of its `&str` to be `'static`, so the elided lifetime is too short, and the compiler complains.

As you probably found if you tried giving the error any lifetime shorter than `'static`, `thiserror` doesn't let you give references any non-static lifetimes because `std::error::Error requires the source is dyn Error + 'static`. So, non-static lifetimes are out of the window as well.

To fix this, you need to make `input` have a  `'static` lifetime. This snippet below compiles:

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

pub fn parse_something(input: &'static str) -> Result<i32, MyError> {

    let (_, number) = nom::character::complete::i32(input)?;
    Ok(number)
}

// define error
#[derive(Error, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("Parsing error in the input")]
    ParseError(#[from] nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&'static str>>),
}
```

---

It may not be possible to have `input` be `'static`, though. In cases where `input` is *not* static, you will need to map the error into a type that contains a `String`. It could look something like this:

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

pub fn parse_something(input: &str) -> Result<i32, MyError> {

    let (_, number) = nom::character::complete::i32(input)
        .map_err(|e: nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>| e.map_input(|input| input.to_string()))?;
    Ok(number)
}

// define error
#[derive(Error, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("Parsing error in the input")]
    ParseError(#[from] nom::Err<nom::error::Error<String>>),
}
```

You can find some more information about difficulty dealing with `nom`'s errors in [this post on the Rust forums](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/lost-in-generic-inference-and-lifetimes-with-nom-and-its-only-a-6-statement-function/68120/2).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to put `map_err()` in every invocation, you can impl `From` and then the `?` operator will do that automatically:

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

pub fn parse_something(input: &str) -> Result<i32, MyError> {
    let (_, number) = nom::character::complete::i32(input)?;
    Ok(number)
}

// define error
#[derive(Error, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("Parsing error in the input")]
    ParseError(nom::Err<nom::error::Error<Box<str>>>),
}

impl From<nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>> for MyError {
    fn from(err: nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>) -> Self {
        Self::ParseError(err.map_input(|input| input.into()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I knew that I could get away with implementing the `From` trait myself. But that defeats the purpose of the `#[from]` macro. Hence my question if there was a way.